# create 1 column from 2 column with in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table is :

my table1 is :

### T1

```
col1    col2
 Con     TB
 Con     TC
 Arr     A
 Arr     B
```

i want this result:

### Result Table

```
column1
 TB#A
 TB#B
 TC#A
 TC#B
```

please write query!!!
tanks

Comment: I suggest reading [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx)

Comment: Don't know why people vote to close this one, this one had more than one incorrect answer, so obviously some people don't know how to do this, it's not the easiest question I've seen at SO either

Comment: @RomanPekar - Because it is a "gimme the codez" question. "please write query!!! tanks" is guaranteed to annoy people.

Comment: @MartinSmith yeah I see if there're would be no last line it would be more polite :) have to agree it's good candidate for closing as it is now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
select 
    a.col2+'#'+b.col2 
from 
    T1 a, T1 b 
where a.col1='Con'and 
    b.col1='Arr'
```

OR

```
select 
    a.col2+'#'+b.col2 
from 
    T1 a CROSS JOIN T1 b 
where a.col1='Con'and 
    b.col1='Arr'
```

Comment: Actually I think it's better to use ANSI joins syntax instead of , syntax

Comment: Yeah @RomanPekar! You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
select T1.col2 + '#' + T2.col2
from Table1 as T1
    cross join Table1 as T2
where T1.col1 = 'Con' and T2.col1 = 'Arr'
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56660/3)</kbd>**

Comment: :) really strange to get downvote for this one.

Comment: '@RomanPekar Not strange, that's how SO works (unfortunately) .. or should work, for at least some guys here.

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE Table1
SET col1 = col + '#' + Col2
```

or Your can Have a new column in your result without changing data in you database

Something like this

```
SELECT CAST(Col1 AS NVARCHAR) + '#' + CAST(Col2 AS NVARCHAR)   AS NewColumn
FROM Table1
```